# how to access files from sftp server?

Tags: php, sftp

```
<?php 
  $localfile = 'test1.txt';
  $fp = fopen ($localfile, "r") or die('Cannot open textfile');
  $connection = ssh2_connect('sftp_server_path/folder',22);
  ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

  $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection) or die ("Cannot connect to server");


  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch,      CURLOPT_URL,"sftp_server_path/folder/test1.txt");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
  if(curl_exec($ch)){
    echo 'File was successfully transferred using SFTP';
  }else{
    echo 'File was unable to be transferred using SFTP';
  }

?>
```

I have the above code to connect and transfer to sftp server and i run this code i am getting message "File was successfully transferred using SFTP". but when i see the folder structure in sftp server i can't see my transfer file on sftp server. what exactly i have to do?

Comment: that means myfolder permissions right ? its 777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$sftp = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($sftp, 'username', 'password');

ssh2_scp_send($sftp, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

Comment: ssh2_scp_send($connection, 'test1.txt', 'foldername/test1.txt', 777);
i used this code. but browser is loading  n loading...........

Comment: sorry should've been `ssh2_scp_send($sftp,` instead of $connection

Answer (score 0):

For portability, I'd recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).  If you want to move to another server utilizing esoteric non-standard extensions like the PECL SSH2 one make doing so more difficult whereas phpseclib makes it pretty much plug and play.